# Can a promise use a struct type?

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct, promise, future

I wonder if it's possible to use a struct as return type of a promise. I looked in the C++ reference, and nothing is stated about a restriction on promise types. All the examples I could find uses promises with int, long, double, string types, but never struct. I modified an example found on the Microsoft (TM)  website, which I slightly modified (the code, not the site). It should work, but I keep having this error :

```
k.cpp: In function ‘void DoSomeWork(int, std::promise<toBeReturned>&)’:
k.cpp:25:9: error: ‘class std::promise<toBeReturned>’ has no member named ‘a’
     ret.a.set_value(it);
         ^
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Can't see if I'm making an unforgivable newbie mistake, or if I ran into something I haven't understood.

Best regards,

MC

Here is the code ---------------------------------------------

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <functional>     // std::ref
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <future>         // std::promise, std::future

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct toBeReturned
    {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    };

void DoSomeWork(int numIters, promise<toBeReturned>& ret)
    {
    int it = 0;
    for ( ; it < numIters; ++it)
        {
        cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " working..." << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(1000));
        }
    ret.a.set_value(it);
    ret.b.set_value(it*10);
    ret.c.set_value(it*100);
    }

void TestPromise()
    {
    int its = 10;
    int i=0;
    bool notDoneYet=true;
    promise<int> myPromise;
    future<int> myFuture = myPromise.get_future();
    thread aThread(DoSomeWork, its, ref(myPromise));
    std::future_status myFutureStatus;

    while(notDoneYet)
        {
        i++;
        try 
            {
            myFutureStatus=myFuture.wait_for(milliseconds(100));
            if(myFuture.valid() && myFutureStatus != future_status::ready)
                {
                cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " waiting..." << endl;
                }
            else if(myFuture.valid() && myFutureStatus == std::future_status::ready)
                {
                toBeReturned valuesToBeReturned;
                try
                    {
                    valuesToBeReturned=myFuture.get();
                    cout << "Work iterations -> a " << a <<  " b " << b <<  " c " << c  << endl;
                    aThread.join();
                    notDoneYet=false;
                    }
                catch (std::future_error& e)
                    {
                    cout << "(2) future_error caught: " << e.code().message() << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (future_error& e)
            {
            cout << "(1) future_error caught: " << e.code().message() << endl;
            }
        }
    }

int main()
    {
    TestPromise();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `ret.a` means to use the member of `promise<toBeReturned>` called `a` , but there is no such member

Comment: Hint: `future<int> myFuture` will not be able to hold a `toBeReturned`, but `future<toBeReturned> myFuture` could. Follow that through and see where you end up.

Comment: Use `set_value` as the promise member. You would pass a `toBeReturned`. Like  ret.set_value(toBeReturned()); Of course, you would initialize 'toBeReturned' with valid data.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks a lot for your clear and useful answers. Indeed it was a total type mismatch mess.

Here is the corrected code :

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <functional>     // std::ref
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <future>         // std::promise, std::future

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

struct toBeReturned
    {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    };

void DoSomeWork(int numIters, promise<toBeReturned>& ret)
    {
    int it = 0;
    toBeReturned tmp; // **********************
    for ( ; it < numIters; ++it)
        {
        cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " working..." << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(1000));
        }
    tmp.a=it; // **********************
    tmp.b=it*10; // **********************
    tmp.c=it*100; // **********************
    ret.set_value(tmp); // **********************
    }

void TestPromise()
    {
    int its = 10;
    int i=0;
    bool notDoneYet=true;
    promise<toBeReturned> myPromise; // **********************
    future<toBeReturned> myFuture = myPromise.get_future(); // **********************
    thread aThread(DoSomeWork, its, ref(myPromise));
    std::future_status myFutureStatus;

    while(notDoneYet)
        {
        i++;
        try 
            {
            myFutureStatus=myFuture.wait_for(milliseconds(100));
            if(myFuture.valid() && myFutureStatus != future_status::ready)
                {
                cout << "Thread " << this_thread::get_id() << " waiting..." << endl;
                }
            else if(myFuture.valid() && myFutureStatus == std::future_status::ready)
                {
                toBeReturned valuesToBeReturned;
                try
                    {
                    valuesToBeReturned=myFuture.get();
                    cout << "Work iterations -> a " << valuesToBeReturned.a <<  " b " << valuesToBeReturned.b <<  " c " << valuesToBeReturned.c  << endl; // **********************
                    aThread.join();
                    notDoneYet=false;
                    }
                catch (std::future_error& e)
                    {
                    cout << "(2) future_error caught: " << e.code().message() << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        catch (future_error& e)
            {
            cout << "(1) future_error caught: " << e.code().message() << endl;
            }
        }
    }

int main()
    {
    TestPromise();
    return 0;
    }
```